# How to get number styles of list displayed in table-row?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to perform the ordering list with display table-row and table-cell but it's removing the numbers from the list.

```
li{
    display: table-row;
}
li span{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF57G/)

So, how can I get the number 1,2,...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS counter in combination with `:before` to number the `li` displayed as `table-row`:

```
ol {
 counter-reset:index;
}
li {
  display: table-row;
  counter-increment: index;
}
li:before {
  content:counter(index)'. ';
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ZF57G/2/)

Comment: That's awesome! Could you also please display another type of display like circle if I do the same in ul instead of ol?

Comment: @C-link well technically, you can use any unicode character to fill the content of the `:before` element, the unicode characters can render many shapes including white bullet, check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ZF57G/7/ That's the easiest way to have some special bullet shape, if you want to customize it more, just try styling the `:before` element with `content:''`. See this demo of mine for such a rich styling http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/Hj8Nn/

Answer (score 0):

Just add following CSS property to your `li`

```
li
{
   display: list-item;
}
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/ZF57G/4/)

good luck!

Comment: I need display table-row not list-item, because list-item displays incorrectly compare with table-row...